# ORA-01843 error when using Date in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle

After looking at most possible solutions I am still getting this exception:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

My query and query call look like this

```
String sql = "select * from my_view "
           + "where TO_DATE(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') "
                  + "between enroll_date and suspend_date "
           + "order by last_name, first_name";

return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        .query(sql, 
               new Object[] { new java.sql.Date(dateOfCall.getTime()) }, 
               new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyDto>(MyDto.class)
              );
```

dateOfCall is of type

```
java.util.Date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind it as date already. So, Oracle implicitly converts it into a String using `TO_CHAR()` in the format as in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Let's Assume `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY'`

Say Date `25th November 2014` gets converted implicitly as `25/11/2014.`

Now a `TO_DATE()` into `MM/DD/YYYY` would probably *error* out because month is mapped with `25` here.

Unless you go for *Abbreviated* months/day in date string.. Just Date is enough. No need to `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` setting.

```
String sql = "select * from my_view "
           + "where ? "
                  + "between enroll_date and suspend_date "
           + "order by last_name, first_name";
```